# Append to a list using a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I am using the following code to assign a value to a given letter (`A = +1, B= -1`)

```
letList = [] 
let1 = ['A','A','B']
count = 0

for l in let1: 
    if l == "A": 
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = count - 1

print(letList.append(count)) #doesnt work
```

**Goal:** I want to create a list of counts with the final output that looks something like this:                                          `letList = [1,2,1]`

**Problem:** But when I try to append using `letList.append(count)` I get a `none` output

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print the append function and the append needs to be in your loop to do what you want. Below is an example that prints [1,2,1] using append.

```
letList = []
let1 = ['A','A','B']
count = 0

for l in let1:
    if l == "A":
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = count - 1

    letList.append(count)

print(letList)
```